# Negate the regex in this string

Tags: regex, pentaho, regex-negation

I have had my head scratching over a simple, but complicated problem for me. And have been trying to find solution as well as doing hit and trials since 5 hours, unfortunately not able to solve.

There is a string which is like "Dept #809 something something something and so on", I need to exclude "Dept #809", and in place of 809 it could be any number 1 to 3 characters long. I am able to match this string using this regex `/^(Dept #(\d{1,3}))/`, but I simply want to exclude this. Have done most of the things, but not able to do :(.

Please help me out!

Comment: Capture the rest with `(.*)`, [e.g. `/^Dept #\d{1,3}(.*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/Vc1inw/1)

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I tried this on regexr.com, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you show me the fiddle?

Comment: http://regexr.com/v1?39677, it selects everything

Comment: But Group 1 contains the value you need. It does not matter what you match, but what you *capture*.

Comment: Ohkay! I see man!!! You are the saviour. Thanks Wiktor!! I can't believe I missed this fact. I am right now working on Pentaho, so this helped me alot! Kudo man!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use plain JavaScript code and depend on a single regex pattern to extract the part of string you need, use a regex to match the beginning of your input, and match *and capture* the rest of the string.

You may do it with

```
/^Dept #\d+(.*)/
```

Or - if there may be line breaks:

```
/^Dept #\d+([\s\S]*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vc1inw/3).

In both case, `Dept #<DIGITS>` is matched at the string start, and the rest is *captured into **Group 1*** that you should be able to access after the match is found.